# Excel VBA: Split Numbers and Text from a string into Columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column in my excel in the following format:

```
Column A
1.2kg
100ml
2m
200
```

I need to run the VBA to split the numbers and text separately into two columns as:

```
Column A | Column B
1.2      |  kg
100      |  ml
2        |  m
200      |
```

I've also found a similar question in this site, however it isn't work for my VBA. Can anyone help me on this?

PS. I use excel 2007

Comment: Post the code you are working on. It can also be achieved through formula. VBA is not required unless you want to have split in place overwriting contents!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested as am on mobile. Does it do what you want?

```
Option Explicit

Sub SplitValuesUnits()

' Code assumes values are on Sheet1. Change sheet name as needed.'

With thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim LastRow as long
LastRow = .cells(.rows.count,"A").end(xlup).row

With .range("A1:B" & LastRow)

Dim ArrayOfValues() as variant
ArrayOfValues = .value2

Dim CharacterIndex as long
Dim RowIndex as long
For RowIndex = lbound(ArrayOfValues,1) to ubound(ArrayOfValues,1)
' Skip zero-length strings, as well as values which are already numbers and do not need splitting '
If len(ArrayOfValues(RowIndex,1)) <> 0 then
If not isnumeric(ArrayOfValues(RowIndex,1)) then

Dim CurrentValue as string
CurrentValue = ArrayOfValues(RowIndex,1)

' Loop through string backwards until we find a numeric value, at which point we assume there are no further non-numeric characters. '
For CharacterIndex = Len(CurrentValue) to 1 Step -1
If isnumeric(mid$(CurrentValue),CharacterIndex,1)) then exit for
Next CharacterIndex

If CharacterIndex >= 1 then
ArrayOfValues(RowIndex,1) = cdbl(left$(CurrentValue,CharacterIndex))
ArrayOfValues(RowIndex,2) = mid$(CurrentValue,CharacterIndex + 1)
End if

End if
End if

Next RowIndex

' Overwrite two columns with values. '
.value2 = arrayofvalues

End with

End with

End sub
```

Comment: This code is work correct to my needed. Thank you for sharing.